# Confusion regarding Limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Our teacher gave us a defination as such

Let $<a_n>$ be a sequence of real nos. Then

$<a_n>$ has limit $l$ iff there are finitely many terms outside every neighborhood of $l$

The sequence $a_n=1+(-1)^n+ \frac{1}{n}$ has clearly two limits $0 & 2$. Now, this clearly goes against the implication above since there exist such neighborhoods for both 0 and 2 which have infinite terms outside of itself

This sequence does not have a limit according to the defination of a limit also(which says $\forall \epsilon >0\,  \exists m\in \mathbb{N}\,  st \forall n>m , a_n\in (l-\epsilon ,l+\epsilon)$) since there exists an $\epsilon $-neighborhood such that for every $m\in \mathbb{N} \, \exists n>m$ such that $a_n \notin (l-\epsilon ,l+\epsilon)$

Where am I wrong

Comment: The sequence does not have a limit. I'm not sure why you think it has limit $0$ or $2$.

Comment: Correct, the sequence does not have a limit, but two [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: @ReinhardMeier thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence you are looking at has two convergent subsequences, the $n$'s such that $a_n = 1/n$ and the $n$'s such that $a_n = 2+1/n$.  These subsequences are both convergent, but that means the sequences as a whole is not, since its long-run behavior never settles down to a particular limit: no matter how large $n$ becomes, there is no $\varepsilon$-ball that contains the remainder of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in thinking that $0$ and $2$ are limits of the **sequence**. As you saw, neither satisfies the definition. They are, however, limit points of the **set**

$$\left\{1+(-1)^n+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;,$$

because every open neighborhood of each of them contains members of that set. Although they are similar, the notions of *limit of a sequence* and *limit point of a set* are actually different concepts and should not be confused.

The opposite situation arises with the sequence given by $a_n=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$: here $0$ is the limit of the sequence, but the set $\{0\}=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ has no limit points at all.

Yet another possibility is exhibited by the sequence given by $a_n=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$: it has subsequences converging to $-1$ and to $1$, but it does not itself converge to any limit, and $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}=\{-1,1\}$ has no limit points.